# Using ParametricNDSolve does not work for certain parameters

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, numerics, eigenvalues

I want to solve the following second-order DE
$$
\ddot{w}(t) H(w(t))+\frac{1}{2}(\dot{w}(t))^2 H'(w(t))+g(w(t))(c_0 (\overline t-\underline t)-w(t)) =0,
$$
with boundary conditions $\dot{w}(\overline t) = 0$ and $\dot{w}(\underline t) = \frac{\overline t-\underline t}{1-G(w(\underline t))}$, and where $H(w)= G(w)(1-G(w))$, $h(w)=H'(w)$, $g(w)=G'(w)$, and $G(\cdot)$ is a cdf.

To do so, I use ParametricNDSolve as follows:

```
c0 = 1;
tinf = 4;
tsup = 5;

(*Uniform distribution fo G(.)*)
csup = 3; 
G[c_] = c/csup;
g[c_] = D[G[c], c];

H[w_] = G[w] (1 - G[w]);
h[w_] = D[H[w], w];

solwa = ParametricNDSolve[{w''[t]*H[w[t]] + 1/2 (w'[t])^2 h[w[t]] + g[w[t]] (c0*(tsup-tinf) - w[t]) == 0, w'[tsup] == 0, w'[tinf] == a}, {w}, {t, tinf, tsup},a]
```

Then, I obtain parameter $a$ as follows:

```
Wat = w /. solwa;
Watinf = w[a][tinf] /. solwa;
aopt = a /. FindRoot[a-(tsup - tinf)/(1 - G[Watinf]), {a,0.5}]
```

With the parameters given above, this works fine ($a \approx 1.1214$) and I get a solution which looks like as expected.

My problem is that, as soon as I change too much the parameters, there seems to have no solutions. For example, if I take `csup=4` instead of `csup=3`, then I get the following error message (at the second stage when solving for $a$)

```
Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0. encountered.

Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0.^2 encountered.

Infinity::indet: Indeterminate expression 0. ComplexInfinity encountered.

Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0. encountered.

General::stop: Further output of Power::infy will be suppressed during this calculation.

Infinity::indet: Indeterminate expression ComplexInfinity+ComplexInfinity+ComplexInfinity encountered.

Infinity::indet: Indeterminate expression 0. ComplexInfinity encountered.

General::stop: Further output of Infinity::indet will be suppressed during this calculation.

ParametricNDSolve::ndnum: Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at t$214883 == 4.`.

ParametricNDSolve::ndnum: Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at t$214883 == 4.`.

FindRoot::nlnum: The function value {1.05555 -1/(1-1/4 ParametricFunction[1,Internal`Bag[<1>],1,1,False,{<<7>>},{<<2>>}][1.05555][4])} is not a list of numbers with dimensions {1} at {a} = {1.05555}.
```

This is problematic since I want to study the solution for a broad set of parameters.

I have the same problem when using a different cdf (for instance $G(w)=1-\exp^{-\lambda w}$).

If someone can help me or point towards an alternative solution, that would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: This is a common problem with solving boundary value problems.  `NDSolve` guesses a value for `w[tinf]`, solves the system as an initial value problem and then adjusts the guess for `w[tinf]` until `w'[tsup] == 0` is satisfied.  If the first guess is not good enough, the calculation may blow up during the iteration process, producing errors of the sort you encountered.  So, suggest a better initial guess by including, for instance, `Method -> {"Shooting", "StartingInitialConditions" -> {w[tinf] == .3}}`.

Comment: My previous comment focused on obtaining `solwa` without errors.  To find `aopt`, try using a better guess for `FindRoot`, for instance, `aopt = a /. FindRoot[a - (tsup - tinf)/(1 - G[Watinf]), {a, 1.2}]`.

Comment: Many thanks once again bbgodfrey!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a more compact approach that obtains `w` and `a` simultaneously.

```
NDSolveValue[{w''[t]*H[w[t]] + 1/2 (w'[t])^2 h[w[t]] + 
    g[w[t]] (c0*(tsup - tinf) - w[t]) == 0, w'[tsup] == 0, w'[tinf] == a[tinf], 
    a'[t] == 0, a[tinf] == (tsup - tinf)/(1 - G[w[tinf]])}, 
    {w, a[tinf]}, {t, tinf, tsup}, 
    Method -> {"Shooting", "StartingInitialConditions" -> {w[tinf] == .3}}]
```

which yields 1.12214 for `a` when `csup = 3`, and 1.08951 for `a` when `csup = 4`.  See https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveBVP.html#3518691 for details.  Note that it may be necessary to adjust `"StartingInitialConditions" -> {w[tinf] == .3}` when other parameters in the calculation are changed.

Comment: Many thanks bbgodfrey, that's super useful!